# Superstrings in the 10th Dimension

Tags: string-theory, universe, big-bang

> *Physicists say that the superstrings vibrating in the 10th dimension are what create the subatomic particles that make up our universe and all other possible universes as well.*

If that is true, then doesn't that disprove the Big Bang theory that our universe was created by essentially a "big bang"? (sorry if my question seems stupid).

Comment: Which physicist says this? Brian Green? lol

Comment: but seriously, you can't think about physics by applying logic to something you hear or read in the media. At least not for this level of abstraction.

Comment: The relation between superstrings and the big bang is completely unclear to me, please elaborate where you see the connection.

Comment: You should be able to apply logic to things in the media. The problem is that media lies.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, string theory is a mathematical hypothesis that is currently speculative. It is a possible candidate for a quantum theory of gravity - a unification of QM with Einstein's theory of gravity - General Relativity. The idea of superstring theory emerged from another theory called supergravity. Supergravity was an attempt at a supersymmetric theory of gravity. Supergravity itself emerged from so-called Kaluza-Klein theories. Kaluza-Klein theory was an attempt to unify gravity with electromagnetism. The problem was that Kaluza-Klein theory was a five-dimensional theory, and GR implied the universe was four-dimensional. Thus, Kaluza-Klein theory proposed to reduce one of the dimensions by "compactifying" it on a torus.

Eventually, supergravity was found to contain inconsistencies. Thus, bosonic and heteroic string theory were born. There were two problems with this theory. One is that it predicted the existence of bosons, but of course, many fundamental particles are fermions (e.g. an electron). Another problem was that bosonic string theory predicted unphysical particles called tachyons (hypothetical particles that could travel faster-than-light). Enter heterotic string theory. Heterotic string theory was based on the theory of symmetry groups and proposed that different "vibrations" of the string resulted in different behaviors of the string. This had the benefit of leading to the cancellation of anomalies - internal mathematical inconsistencies within the theory.

Now, enter modern superstring theory. Modern superstring theory is attempt to unify the four fundamental forces and quantize gravity. It is based on the concept of dualities - symmetries that reveal two aspects of the same physical theory. For example, T-duality and S-duality. String theory proposes that the extra dimensions are compactified to a very, very small scale (well below the Planck scale) and it thus attempts to "reproduce" the observable four-dimensional spacetime of GR.

References:

http://superstringtheory.com/basics/basic6a.html

http://whystringtheory.com/toolbox/dualities/

http://www.superstringtheory.com/basics/basic5a.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterotic_string_theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bosonic_string_theory

[http://www.amazon.com/String-Theory-Dummies-Andrew-Zimmerman/dp/047046724X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047046724X)
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/string-theory-five-theories.html

Comment: May I ask you where you got the idea that string theory emerged out of supergravity? Originally, string theory arose in an attempt to describe scattering amplitudes for hadrons, and only later was reinterpreted as a theory of (quantum-)gravity from which one recovers supergravity at low energy.

Comment: From this website: http://www.superstringtheory.com/basics/basic7.html.

Comment: Brunner is right, that is the history.

Comment: I am sure he is. I was likely simply misinformed at the time.